# Overlap WPF Forms by DirectShow works on some PC but fail on others

Tags: wpf, directshow

thanks in advance.

I want to do a 0.5 opacity image overlap on the video from camera (watermark purpose).

It works fine when I use Microsoft EE4. But EE4 would fail to get camera in Oracle Virtual Box (Win10).

Then I turn to DirectShow, it solves my issue on Oracle Virtual Box, and also can work on some PC. The DirectShow library is refer to this project: https://github.com/jacobbo/WebEye

But it's very strange that not every machine can overlap well, in my notebook, when I load the camera video display window, my other overlap forms can't be transparent on it.

[The effect I expect to see:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqL5P.png)
[I can see the video on the screen, but screenshot is black, transparent overlap also fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umbq5.png)
I am confuse why some PC works fine but others fail, I am wondering maybe here is the root cause, but after some try run on it, still can't work.

```
protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hWndParent)
{
RECT clientArea;
GetClientRect(hWndParent.Handle, out clientArea);

_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "Static", "", WindowStyles.WS_CHILD | WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE | WindowStyles.WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPED, 0, 0, clientArea.right - clientArea.left, clientArea.bottom - clientArea.top, hWndParent.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Then I step into the DirectShowFacade.cpp source code. Actually, I don't know how to trace into it since I am far away from win32 API. But it makes me very confuse that why the same code can have different behaviors, WPF form transparent overlap on video output are success at some devices with win7 and win10, but some are fail!?

```
void OnPaint(HWND hWnd) 
{ 
    if (g_spWindowlessControl != NULL && g_GraphIsRunning)
    {
        // Paint the window's client area. 
        PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
        HDC hdc = ::BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); 

        // Request the VMR to paint the video.
        HRESULT hr = g_spWindowlessControl->RepaintVideo(hWnd, hdc);  
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hr); // Suppress a 'not referenced' warning in Release build. 

        ::EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In order to make a *real* and *reliably working* watermark on a camera live image that you obtain via DirectShow, I would suggest you to create a custom DirectShow filter with one input pin and one output pin. That filter would draw a watermark directly on the frame images. You can then insert this filter into your DirectShow graph. If you're interested, I can post some code so you know where to start. This isn't that hard actually.

Comment: Thanks your recommendation, I think use custom filter is a right way for watermark. But in my usage, my purpose is not only watermark texts or pics, I will do some drawing on the screen with transparent background which is overlap on the video, therefore, I need screen capture with transparent overlap. I think this kind of low level control have to turn to C++ and Win32API. WPF maybe not a good choice for image processing?